# How can I modify the axes values of a ggplot bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with three categorical variables from a dataset and I'd like to graph them in a bar graph with ggplot2 with this code:

```
newbrfss2013 %>% 
    filter(!is.na(misdeprd)) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(smokday2)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=exerany2, fill = smokday2)) +
      geom_bar(position="dodge") + facet_wrap( ~ misdeprd, ncol=3)
```

However I'm obtaining for some panels pretty good graphs but for others the numbers are too small that i cannot see the bars clearly:

[image: 1]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you *might* be looking for the `scales="free"` argument to `facet_wrap`.  Fine control over axes in a faceted plot is, unfortunately, not something ggplot is good at.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly